# regex for complex passwords

Tags: regex

Requirement is start with one alpha 
has a number
has both lower and upper case alpha
has special character.
my regex almost gets this:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$_!%\*])([a-zA-Z0-9@#$_!%\*]+)
```

Tried against and does not pass as expected

```
e2~Sertty
2e!Sertty
E2sertty
pers1234!

Apers1234! should work but does not
R4pers1234! same
Rtpers1234!

pApers1234! does work
TAers1234! works
```

Ideas?

**I removed the length requirement for now but wanted to have min length of 8

Comment: Does it have to have a single regex?

Comment: Does it have to be a single regex? If you test these independently, they're much simpler. Any time you're using lookaheads and lookbehinds, it's a good time to reevaluate...

Comment: For this particular policy, yes we want to have the redundancy that other policies may enforce (e.g. require a numeric)

Comment: A regex is probably not the best, or even the most efficient, way to accomplish this...

Comment: I agree @twalberg but this is what is being requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$_!%\*])([a-zA-Z0-9@#$_!%\*]+)
```

works for these :

```
Apers1234! should work but does not
R4pers1234! same
Rtpers1234!
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you're matching `[a-zA-Z]` first before the lookaheads.

This should work:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*[@#$_%\*!])([a-zA-Z][\w@#$!%*]{7,})$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZ8fD4/1)